# Best way to keep common library code in .net application

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, .net-core, .net-standard

I am working on a project where i have multiple microservices. Each microservice is a VS solution file and they are in .net core 2.1. Now there are some common libraries which are used across all microservices which are in .net standard. I would like to know some idea from the community as to what is the best way to reference these .net standard common library project between different microservices. Suppose i make some change in one common library which is used by all the microservices then i will have to deploy all the other microservices so that the common library projects latest code is reflected in all other microservices. Is there a better way so that i don't have to redeploy all microservices?
This will run in Linux.

Comment: Why not make that another service instead of a dll? that way, your other services will only work with an API and you only need to redeploy them if the API changes...

Comment: It would be useful to understand what the constraints are such that all services "have" to be running the same version of the common library (as indicated by your "I will have to deploy all..." comment). We have a number of services and common libraries and (for most of the common libraries)we usually only update the common libraries for a particular service if we're making changes to it for other reasons.